# Webmatrix Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, passwords, localhost

I have a problem with a mysqli_query in this code:

```
  <?php

  session_start();
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
  include "connect.php";


  if ($user && $pwd){

  // infos provided
  $queryget=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Tmembers WHERE user='$user' AND pwd='$pwd'");
  $numrows=mysqli_num_rows("$queryget");

 if ($numrows !=0){
                    $_SESSION['user'] =$user;
                    echo "you have successfully logged in .";
                  }

 else echo "you r not a member, please sign in  ";
               }

                else{
                        echo "you didn't enter any entries !!!";
                        include "connect.php";
                     }
  ?>
```

it returns this error : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I am working on webmatrix, with a Mysql database not (sql server) and I connected to it successfuly via connect.php, and it has a password, the table Tmembers has two colomns user and pwd, I don't know how to fix this access bug

Comment: looks like a mysql_connect authentication issue to me... can you post the content of connect.php?

Comment: yes it does but it is not, here is mysqli_query :
     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "lost01","Members") or die("Connexion Impossible : " . mysqli_error());
and it returns no error

Comment: right. but in this case the error message shouldn't be "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"...? is like there's no user. are you using the correct path to connect.php?

Comment: yes I am using the correct path,when I leave the entries empty is gives me echo "you didn't enter any entries !!!"; that means the problem comes from this login.php right ?

Answer (score 0):

The error states no password was specified even though it exists in the code. So basically the  error does not match the statement `mysqli_connect("localhost", "root"...` which means the database thinks you aren't even attempting to connect in the first place.

Try replacing `mysqli_connect()` with `mysql_connect()` see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) should be the connection resource from your connect statement. Then pass your sql query string as a second parameter.